# troubles at rendering the form field label in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

When I tried to render field label, that contains HTML tags, in the template, it was rendered to the simple text.

```
erotrotsity = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, label='Erot<sup>12</sup>', required=False, validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])
```

filter |safe and autoescape don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`mark_safe()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe):

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

erotrotsity = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=3, label=mark_safe('Erot<sup>12</sup>'), required=False, validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])
```